# Golang upload Http request FormFile to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm creating a micro service to handle some attachments uploads to Amazon S3, What I'm trying to achieve is accept a file and then store it directly to my Amazon S3 bucket, my current function :

```
func upload_handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  file, header, err := r.FormFile("attachment")

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    return
  }

  defer file.Close()

  fileSize, err := file.Seek(0, 2) //2 = from end
    if err != nil {
         panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("File size : ", fileSize)

  bytes := make([]byte, fileSize)
  // read into buffer
  buffer := bufio.NewReader(file)
  _, err = buffer.Read(bytes)

  auth := aws.Auth{
        AccessKey: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        SecretKey: "SECRET_KEY_HERE",
  }
  client := s3.New(auth, aws.EUWest)
  bucket := client.Bucket("attachments")

  err = bucket.Put(header.Filename, bytes, header.Header.Get("Content-Type"), s3.ACL("public-read"))

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
}
```

The problem is that the files stored in S3 are all corrupted, After a small verification it seems that the file payload is not read as bytes

How to convert the file to bytes and store it correctly to S3 ?

Comment: For community knowledge, why does this question receive a negative rating? It is asking a clear question, has  sufficient code, and seemingly correct ref tags. +1 for Q and A for me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ioutil.ReadAll`:

```
bs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
// ...
err = bucket.Put(
    header.Filename, 
    bs, 
    header.Header.Get("Content-Type"), 
    s3.ACL("public-read"),
)
```

`Read` is a lower-level function which has subtle behavior:

> Read reads data into p. It returns the number of bytes read into p. It calls Read at most once on the underlying Reader, hence **n may be less than len(p)**. At EOF, the count will be zero and err will be io.EOF.

So what was probably happening was some subset of the file data was being written to S3 along with a bunch of 0s.

`ioutil.ReadAll` works by calling `Read` over and over again filling a dynamically expanding buffer until it reaches the end of the file. (so there's no need for the `bufio.Reader` either)

Also the `Put` function will have issues with large files (using `ReadAll` means the entire file must fit in memory) so you may want to use [`PutReader`](http://godoc.org/launchpad.net/goamz/s3#Bucket.PutReader) instead:

```
bucket.PutReader(
    header.Filename, 
    file, 
    fileSize, 
    header.Header.Get("Content-Type"), 
    s3.ACL("public-read"),
)
```

Comment: with both solutions the content length of the saved file is 0, when I try to write the file on local storage I can read it contents